# One question on 1st-order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

> Given a smooth vector field $\mathbf{b}$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, let
>   $\mathbf{x}(s)=\mathbf{x}(s,x,t)$ solve the ODE
>   $$\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{x}) (s\in\mathbb{R}), x(t)=x.$$
>
> (a) Define the Jacobian
>   $$J(s,x,t):=\det D_x\mathbf{x}(s,x,t)$$
>   and derive the Euler formula
>   $$J_s=\operatorname{div} \mathbf{b}(\mathbf{x})J.$$
>
> (b) Set $$u(x,t):=g(\mathbf{x}(0,x,t))J(0,x,t).$$ Show that $u(x,t)$
>   solves the equation
>   $$u_t+\operatorname{div}(u\mathbf{b}(x))=0, \mbox{ in } \mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}_+,$$
>   with the initial value $u(x,0)=g(x)$.

This is an exercise in L. Evans' classic textbook "Partial
differential equations (2nd Edition)", page 162-163. We have solved
(a). Now we are focusing on (b). Evans gave a hint on (b): one
should show $\frac{\partial}{\partial s}(u(\mathbf{x},s)J)=0$
firstly.

We have tried the characteristic method and some other methods,
however, we are not able to work it out. Thanks for all of your
help!